# Initialzer for conditional binding must have Optional type not 'String'

Tags: swift

Compiler is throwing an error "Initialzer for conditional binding must have Optional type not 'String'"

```
if let classString = String.fromCString(class_getName(currentVeiw?.dynamicType)){
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is telling you that you can't use an if let because it's totally unnecessary. You don't have any optionals to unwrap.if let is used exclusively to unwrap optionals. Simply use:

```
let classString = String(describing: type(of: currentVeiw!))
```